# decrease variable value to zero by values of another variables

Tags: php

I know it might be voted down, but I really need help, I can't think anymore, I have 4 variables, and I need to decrease one of them by values of the other 3, till it come to zero.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$total=10;
$var1=3;
$var2=4;
$var3=7;

echo "total: ".$total."<br>";
echo "var1: ".$var1."<br>";
echo "var2: ".$var2."<br>";
echo "var3: ".$var3."<hr>";

while($total>$var1){
    if($total>=$var1){
        $total= $total-$var1;
        echo "total: ".$total."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

result:

```
total: 10
var1: 3
var2: 4
var3: 7

total: 7
total: 4
total: 1
```

off course it is not the result I'm looking for, but I need:

```
total: 10
var1: 3
var2: 4
var3: 7

total: 7
var1: 0
var2: 4
var3: 7

total: 3
var1: 0
var2: 0
var3: 6

total: 0
var1: 0
var2: 0
var3: 3
```

I stuck here and I need thoughts if you please.

and what if one of the variables more than Total?

thanks

**EDIT**

I know the solution is:

```
if($total>0){
    if($var1>=$total){
        $var1=$var1-$total;
        $total=0;
    }else{
        $total=$total-$var1;
        $var1=0;

        if($var2>=$total){
            $var2=$var2-$total;
            $total=0;
        }else{
            $total=$total-$var2;
            $var2=0;

            if($var3>=$total){
                $var3=$var3-$total;
                $total=0;
            }else{
                $total=$total-$var3;
                $var3=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "total: ".$total."<br>";
echo "var1: ".$var1."<br>";
echo "var2: ".$var2."<br>";
echo "var3: ".$var3."<hr>";
```

But, what If I has 30 variables?!!! I need a simple solution

Comment: could you please elaborate the requirement of total: 10
var1: 3
var2: 4
var3: 7

total: 7
var1: 0
var2: 4
var3: 7

total: 3
var1: 0
var2: 0
var3: 6

total: 0
var1: 0
var2: 0
var3: 3

Comment: Gugan - misread your problem first time, so changed it - I think this is what you wanted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  Re-read your question and decided I had misunderstood what you wanted.  This should work for your numbers, or any number, whether or not the total can be zeroed.

```
<?php
$var = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$total = 40;
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++ ) {
    $varn = "var" . ($i+1);
    if ($total > $var[$i]) {
        $result[$varn] = 0;
        $total -= $var[$i];
    } else {
        $result[$varn] = $var[$i] - $total;
        $total = 0;
    }
}
$result = ["total"=>$total] + $result;
var_export($result);
?>
```

This yields the output:

```
array (
  'total' => 0,
  'var1' => 0,
  'var2' => 0,
  'var3' => 4,
)
```

Here is an example using :

```
$var = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$total = 20;
```

Which produces:

```
array (
  'total' => 0,
  'var1' => 0,
  'var2' => 0,
  'var3' => 0,
  'var4' => 0,
  'var5' => 3,
  'var6' => 7,
  'var7' => 8,
)
```

And:

```
$var = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$total = 40;
```

Yielding:

```
array (
  'total' => 2,
  'var1' => 0,
  'var2' => 0,
  'var3' => 0,
  'var4' => 0,
  'var5' => 0,
  'var6' => 0,
  'var7' => 0,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them into an array:

```
$total = 10
$var = array (3,4,7);
foreach ($var as &$value)   //  Reference so setting $value changes array
{
    if  $total >= $value)
    {
        $total -= $value;
        $value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $value -= $total;
        $total = 0;
        break;     //  Stop processing now
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate your efforts, but result not quite i'm looking for, cause your result will give me: **total: 0** - **var1: 3** - **var2: 4** - **var3: 7** while I need it to be  **total: 0** - **var1: 0** - **var2: 0** - **var3: 4**